# Backbone.js collection and sortedIndex always returning 0

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm having trouble getting the `sortedIndex` underscore method to return a useful value. I have a collection with a comparator, and that's adding models correctly in order. I would just like to know the potential index of a new model, and the `sortedIndex` method is return 0 matter what I try.

```
var Chapter  = Backbone.Model;
var chapters = new Backbone.Collection;

chapters.comparator = function(chapter) {
  return chapter.get("page");
};

chapters.add(new Chapter({page: 9, title: "The End"}));
chapters.add(new Chapter({page: 5, title: "The Middle"}));
chapters.add(new Chapter({page: 1, title: "The Beginning"}));

var foo = new Chapter({ page: 3, title: 'Bar' });

// Will always return 0 no matter the value of page in foo.
console.log(chapters.sortedIndex(foo));
```

I know there's something wrong in there, or perhaps that's no the intention of sortedIndex but I'm unsure either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is Underscore.js knows nothing about the `comparator` function of the collection and expects comparator as an argument of `sortedIndex` function. This will work as expected:

```
console.log(chapters.sortedIndex(foo, chapters.comparator));
```